# Stop pixel font from being blurred when rendered

Tags: javascript, antialiasing, pixi.js

I am trying to create a little game in a pixel retro look and I am using a pixelated font. Unfortunately I am unable to render the font with edges as sharp as they are in the source font.

#### About my mcve:

I am using [this](https://fontmeme.com/fonts/pokemon-classic-font/) font for `fonts/pokemon_classic.ttf` (I found no way to host that font online, so no jsfiddle), but you can use any pixel font you like.
The example below renders the font like this:

[image: screenshot of blurry text]

How can I make this text render as sharp as it is in the source font? It should look like this (edited image):

[image: edited blurry image which shows the text sharp]

the scale of `root` may change during runtime to fit the screen

A less elegant solution which would probably work is to fix the alpha of each pixel to be either `0` or `1` depending on some threshold, but I don't know how to do this.

#### JS:

```js
PIXI.settings.SCALE_MODE = PIXI.SCALE_MODES.NEAREST;
let scale = 30;
let app = new PIXI.Application();
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

app.renderer.view.style.position = "absolute";
app.renderer.view.style.display = "block";
app.renderer.autoResize = true;
app.renderer.resize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

let root = new PIXI.Container();
app.stage.addChild(root);
root.scale.set(scale);

document.fonts.load('8pt "pokemon"').then(() => {
    let text = new PIXI.Text("Test", {fontFamily: 'pokemon', fontSize: 8, fill: 0xff1010});
    root.addChild(text);
});
```

#### CSS:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'pokemon';
    src: url("fonts/pokemon_classic.ttf");
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are using some small text in the example. Text can be blurry in PIXI when you set the font size to a small number. To fix this, you can just set the font size to 2 or 3 times bigger than you want it to be and then use scale.set() to change it back to its original size. By doing this, It will have a better resolution.

Answer (score 4):

Things that can make text blurry....

1. `SCALE_MODE`
2. Sub-pixel positioning. Turn on `roundPixels` when creating new `PIXI.Application` for v4, v5 you can set globally via `PIXI.settings.ROUND_PIXELS = true;`, or indivudally, `displayObject.roundPixels = true;`
3. Scaling

So you're good on #1, but #2 and #3 could be issues.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, but "X could be an issue" is not an answer and should be a comment instead. I have tried suggestion #2 and it didn't help. The general pointer in #3 didn't help me either.

Comment: Blurring of text in PixiJS can be any one of a variety of issues, and sometimes a combination, so I believe it's acceptable for me to say "try x or y".
#3 - You are scaling the root stage  with `root.scale.set(scale);` That can cause bluriness. Try without scaling the base stage

Comment: it is acceptable, but not on SO. SO answers should contain real answers to the question. If you have a suggestion or want to inquire further information, it is meant to go to a comment below the question. I don't want to come across as rude or like I don't appreciate your help, I am just trying to make you aware of that fact.

Comment: Also about the suggestion not to scale the root stage: I need to scale the stage. This is how I adjust the size of the whole application. It will be scaled differently, depending on the screen size and resolution. If I had to ditch scaling the stage, I'd have to resort to some other form of scaling - of which I am unfortunately unaware

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end? I'm struggling with the same problem and would really appreciate any help :)

Comment: @cwirz yea, I did, but you won't like it. I painted the text to a separate texture. Afterwards I iterated over every (!) pixel. With a treshhold I decided if the pixel is supposed to be black or white. In my case the variety of texts wasn't that big, so when retrieving such a texture, I always saved them to a dictionary. this way every text only had to be rendered once and could be reused

Comment: Setting `text.roundPixels = true` on my text made it sharp, but it moves and now the movement is jumpy and nervous looking. Making the text twice as large in the style and setting `text.scale.set(0.5)` helps a little but now it sort of shimmers while moving.

Comment: What worked well for me was to use positioned <div>s floating above the PIXI canvas for my labels. Sharp text and smooth movement.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by setting `resolution` like this:

```
text.resolution = window.devicePixel * scale
```

It will re-render the text leading to bad performance, so I just apply it for the last value of `scale`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having a double resolution for the whole app...

My Pixi.js text and textures were blurry.
I increased the resolution of the whole Pixi app.
Then your canvas size will double.
You can then you `options.autoDensity` to fit double resolution in the same canvas. https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Application.html

```
// Pixi.js API from v6.5.1
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'; 

PIXI.settings.PRECISION_FRAGMENT = PIXI.PRECISION.HIGH; // might help a bit
PIXI.settings.ROUND_PIXELS = true; // might help a bit
PIXI.settings.RESOLUTION = 2;

const app = new PIXI.Application({ width: 750, height: 400, autoDensity: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution:

text.resolution = 2